# Is it possible to use the same File for reading and writing?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to use the same `std::fs::File` object for writing and reading, but reading returns an empty string.

I tried to `flush`, `sync_all` and `seek`, but nothing helped. With a new `File` object I can read the file easily.

```
use std::io::{Read, Seek, Write};

const FILE_PATH: &str = "test.txt";

fn main() {
    // Create file
    let mut f = std::fs::File::create(FILE_PATH).unwrap();
    f.write_all("foo bar".as_bytes());
    f.seek(std::io::SeekFrom::Start(0));

    // Read from the same descriptor
    let mut content = String::new();
    f.read_to_string(&mut content);
    println!("{:?}", content); // -> ""

    // Read from the other descriptor
    let mut f = std::fs::File::open(FILE_PATH).unwrap();
    let mut content = String::new();
    f.read_to_string(&mut content);
    println!("{:?}", content); // -> "foo bar"
}
```

Comment: You didn't handle/log/unwrap any of the `Result`s, which probably would have shown the problem. Don't ignore the compiler warnings!

Comment: Thanks for the notice @Stefan! You're right, in real program we should respect compiler's warnings. But this piece of code was needed only to show the problem clearly, without distracting details.

Comment: If I unwrap the `read_to_string` result I get a "Bad file descriptor" error - which tells me it just doesn't want to read from it, no matter the `flush`, `sync_all` and `seek` calls. Not unwrapping the errors and then wondering about the result is "not showing any research effort" in my eyes. So in a real program you should *handle* the errors, in examples you should at least unwrap the `Result`s.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem was with `File::create` — it [opens a file in write-only mode](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html#method.create). The fix is to use [`std::fs::OpenOptions`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.OpenOptions.html):

```
let mut f = std::fs::OpenOptions::new()
    .create(true)
    .write(true)
    .read(true)
    .open(FILE_PATH)
    .unwrap();
```

Don't forget to reset the reading position with `seek`.